# Display second layer of array based upon first key with SMARTY

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, html-table, smarty, multi-index

I'm having issues to display the following array into a table. The idea is to display the data horizontal based upon the first array, yet the 2nd array also should be accessed and displayed horizontal.

The array (I reversed the array for display purposes):

```
    Array ( 
    [3] => Array ( 
         [name] => Joop 
         [details] => Array ( 
                      [length] => 184
                      [weight] => 86
                      ...
                      ) 
         [year] => 1984
         [university] => Harvard 
         [class_id] => 37 
         [group_id] => 14 
         ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
         [name] => Tim 
         [details] => Array ( 
                      [length] => 169
                      [weight] => 74
                      ...
                      ) 
         [year] => 1977
         [university] => MIT 
         [class_id] => 37 
         [group_id] => 14 
         ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
         [name] => Kelly 
         [details] => Array ( 
                      [length] => 164 
                      [weight] => 51
                      ...
                      ) 
         [year] => 1982
         [university] => MIT 
         [class_id] => 37 
         [group_id] => 14 
         ) 
    [0] => Array ( 
         [name] => Alex 
         [details] => Array ( 
                      [lenght] => 172
                      [weight] => 79
                      ...
                      ) 
         [year] => 1979
         [university] => Harvard
         [class_id] => 37 
         [group_id] => 14 
         )
```

I wish to display it in a HTML table as follows:

```
Name | Joop | Tim | Kelly | Alex
Length | 184 | 169 | 164 | 172
weight | 86 | 74 | 51 | 79
...
...
Year | 1984 | 1977 | 1982 | 1979
university | Harvard | MIT | MIT | Harvard
```

I have tried it inside my template with a foreach and loop combination, yet I'm unable to display the details part correctly.

Any have a clue how to tackle this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to loop the keys of the first array and then again every one of them

```
{foreach $arr.0 as $row=>$wathever}
<tr><td>{$row}</td>
{foreach $arr as $col}
<td>{$col.$row}</td>
{/foreach}
</tr>
{/foreach}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution as followed:

```
{foreach key=key item=item from=$arr}<th>{$item.name}</th>
{/foreach}
{foreach item=item  key=key from=$arr.0.details}
  <tr><td>{$key}</td>
    {section name=arrloop loop=$arr}
    <td>{$arr[arrloop].details.$key}</td>
    {/section}
  </tr>
{/foreach}
```